# How to validate XML against XSD in PHP

Tags: validation, xsd, schema, libxml2

I have tried to validate my XML against XSD by following way.

```
<?php
     $xml= new DOMDocument;
     $xml->load(xml path);
     if ($xml->schemaValidate(xsd path)) {print "valid.\n";} else {print "invalid.\n";}
?>
```

It gives me following error

```
DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}attribute': The content is not valid. Expected is (annotation?).
```

To see the error detail I add the      `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` in validation code as you can see below.

```
<?php
     libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
     $xml= new DOMDocument;
     $xml->load(xml path);
     if ($xml->schemaValidate(xsd path)) {print "valid.\n";} else {print "invalid.\n";}
?>
```

After adding this I got following warning

```
Severity: Warning
Message: DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Invalid Schema
```

I validated this xml online against my xsd and it is valid.However, in my php code it gives me error and I google these errors and it says the document could be invalid while I am sure the document is correct as I have validated it online. I am bit new in this so may be there is some mistake I am doing in validation code but unable to see.

Here is XML

```
<Application xmlns="NextGenMALI-Schema" Type="NewApplication">
    <Identifier>1584928194</Identifier>
    <SalesChannel SalesChannelType="Broker">
        <Identifier>I12345</Identifier>
        <CompanyName BusinessName="National Finance and Loans"/>
        <PersonName>
            <NameTitle Value="Mr"/>
            <FirstName>Jonson</FirstName>
            <Surname>Jonson</Surname>
        </PersonName>
        <RelatedEntityRef Type="crm_id">abc@yahoo.com</RelatedEntityRef>
        <Email>abc@yahoo.com</Email>
    </SalesChannel>
    <SalesChannel SalesChannelDescription="BDM">
        <Identifier/>
        <PersonName>
            <Surname/>
        </PersonName>
    </SalesChannel>
    <Comment>Test comments.</Comment>
    <PartySegment>
        <Party Type="Applicant" PrimaryApplicant="Yes">
            <Identifier>4</Identifier>
            <Privacy AllowCreditCheck="Yes" AllowDirectMarketing="No" SignatureVerification="No" PointVerificationCompleted="No" ExistingCustomer="Yes" AllowThirdPartyDisclosure="Yes">
                <PointVerification DocumentType="DriversLicenceAust" DocumentNumber="12345" NameOnDocument="Josie Ann Test" VersionSighted="Original" VerificationCategory="Primary" Photographic="Yes" NameVerified="Yes" AddressVerified="Yes" SignatureVerified="Yes" DOBVerified="Yes">
                    <PlaceOfIssue>
                        <City>NSW</City>
                    </PlaceOfIssue>
                    <EndDate>2014-11-28</EndDate>
                </PointVerification>
                <DocumentsSightedBy LoanWriter="No"/>
            </Privacy>
            <ResponsibleLend/>
            <Person FirstHomeBuyer="Yes" CustomerOfLender="Yes" EmployeeOfLender="Yes" Director="No" PreviousName="Jones" Sex="Female">
                <PersonName>
                    <NameTitle Value="Mr"/>
                    <FirstName>First Name</FirstName>
                    <OtherName>Middle Name</OtherName>
                    <Surname>Surname</Surname>
                </PersonName>
                <DateOfBirth>1993-02-01</DateOfBirth>
                <MaritalStatus Status="Single" OtherDescription=""/>
                <Dependent Age="2"/><Dependent Age="4"/>
                <MothersMaidenName>Mother Maiden Name</MothersMaidenName>
                <Residency PermanentInAustralia="Yes" Status="Citizen">
                    <Country ISO3166="AU"/>
                </Residency>
                <ContactDetails>
                    <AddressDetails Residential="Yes" Mailing="No" PriorAddress="No" PostSettlement="No" HousingStatus="Boarding">
                    <RelatedEntityRef>45e7815c217b8a</RelatedEntityRef>
                        <StartAndEndDates><StartDate>2019-04-04</StartDate></StartAndEndDates>
                    </AddressDetails><AddressDetails Residential="No" Mailing="No" PriorAddress="No" PostSettlement="No" HousingStatus="Caravan">
                    <RelatedEntityRef>45e7815c217ba4</RelatedEntityRef>
                        <StartAndEndDates><StartDate>2017-02-02</StartDate><EndDate>2017-02-02</EndDate></StartAndEndDates>
                    </AddressDetails><AddressDetails Residential="No" Mailing="No" PriorAddress="No" PostSettlement="No" HousingStatus="Renting">
                    <RelatedEntityRef>45e7815c217bac</RelatedEntityRef>
                        <StartAndEndDates><StartDate>2015-03-01</StartDate><EndDate>2015-03-01</EndDate></StartAndEndDates>
                    </AddressDetails>


                    <Email PreferredContactMethod="Yes">asd@yahoo.com</Email>
                </ContactDetails>
                <Employment OnProbation="No" PrimaryEmployment="Yes" PriorEmployment="No" Role="1112-11" RoleDescription="General Manager">
                    <PAYE Type="FullTime">
                        <RelatedEntityRef Type="RelatedParty">1097796810218</RelatedEntityRef>
                    </PAYE>
                    <StartAndEndDates>
                        <StartDate>2005-01-01</StartDate>
                    </StartAndEndDates>
                    <EmploymentIncome>
                        <ValueItem Value="10000">
                            <Identifier>IDARAHXC-Income</Identifier>
                            <Income Type="OtherIncome">
                                <Period Unit="Monthly">
                                    <StartDate>2013-07-01</StartDate>
                                    <EndDate>2014-06-30</EndDate>
                                </Period>
                            </Income>
                        </ValueItem>
                    </EmploymentIncome>
                </Employment>
            </Person>
        </Party>
    </PartySegment>
    <AddressSegment>

                                <AddressWrapper>
                                    <Identifier>45e7815c217b8a</Identifier>
                                    <Address>
                                        <StreetNo>8</StreetNo><Street Type="Street">Street</Street><City>Melbourne</City><State Name="VIC"/><Postcode>3000</Postcode>
                                        <Country ISO3166="AU"/>
                                    </Address>
                                </AddressWrapper>

                                <AddressWrapper>
                                    <Identifier>45e7815c217ba4</Identifier>
                                    <Address>
                                        <StreetNo>4</StreetNo><Street Type="Street">Street</Street><City>Melville</City><State Name="WA"/><Postcode>6153</Postcode>
                                        <Country ISO3166="AU"/>
                                    </Address>
                                </AddressWrapper>

                                <AddressWrapper>
                                    <Identifier>45e7815c217bac</Identifier>
                                    <Address>
                                        <StreetNo>7</StreetNo><Street Type="Street">Street</Street><City>Shire of Mornington Peninsula</City><State Name="VIC"/><Postcode>3941</Postcode>
                                        <Country ISO3166="AU"/>
                                    </Address>
                                </AddressWrapper>

    </AddressSegment>


    <FinancialSegment NoOtherAssets="No" NoLiabilities="No" NoIncome="No">
    <ValueItem Value="41000">
            <Identifier>1097796822609</Identifier>
            <OwnedByAllApplicants/>
            <Asset Class="CurrentSecurity" SecurityType="RegisteredMortgage">
                <RealEstate Transaction="Purchasing" PrimarySecurity="Yes" PropertyPrimaryPurpose="OwnerOccupied" ApprovalInPrinciple="No" Status="Established" Holding="Sole">
                    <Residential WillOwn3UnitsInComplex="No" WillOwn25PercentOfComplex="No" OffThePlan="No" Type="FullyDetachedHouse"/>
                    <EstimatedValue>41000</EstimatedValue>
                    <ContractPrice LicencedRealEstateAgentContract="No" ContractPriceAmount="41000"/>
                    <VisitContact Type="Customer"/>
                    <Location>
                        <RelatedEntityRef>1415066564285</RelatedEntityRef>
                        <Title TitleType="Torrens" TenureType="Freehold"/>
                    </Location>
                </RealEstate>
            </Asset>
        </ValueItem>
</FinancialSegment>
    <RelatedPartySegment>
        <RelatedParty RelPartyType="Lender">
                <Identifier>1097796817156</Identifier>
                <CompanyName BusinessName="AMP"/>
        </RelatedParty>
    </RelatedPartySegment>


    <LoanDetailSegment>
        <LoanDetails>
            <Identifier>1097796802265</Identifier>
            <EstimatedSettlement>2014-11-28</EstimatedSettlement>
            <LoanPurpose PrimaryPurpose="OwnerOccupied" OwnerBuilderApplication="No">
                <LendingPurposeCode ABSCode="ABS-125" PurposeAmount="0.0" Description="Affinity Fixed Rate, 1 Year (Investment)"/>
            </LoanPurpose>
            <LoanPortion ProductName="Affinity Fixed Rate, 1 Year (Investment)" ProductCode="AFFR1I" StatementCycle="Monthly" PackageName="">
                <Identifier>1097796802265-1</Identifier>
                <LoanTerm Units="Years" Type="TotalTerm">30</LoanTerm>
                <LoanTerm Units="Years" Type="Variable" PaymentType="PrincipalAndInterest"/>
                <AmountRequested Amount="41315" BaseAmount="41315"/>
                <PaymentPeriod Payments="0.0">
                    <Period Unit="Monthly"/>
                </PaymentPeriod>
            </LoanPortion>
        </LoanDetails>
        <Representation Self="No">
            <NominatedRepresentation>
                <RelatedEntityRef>1415066458059</RelatedEntityRef>
            </NominatedRepresentation>
        </Representation>
    </LoanDetailSegment>
    <CrossSellSegment Enabled="true"/>
</Application>
<!-- NGPH: 237119.297 -->
```

Please find XSD here (Word limit exceeds so I had to upload it to share with you)
https://easyupload.io/qifnk1
password: myxsd

Comment: It seems that libxml2 doesn't support `xs:attribute` with `use="prohibited"` and `xs:simpleType` content. Probably a bug in libxml2.

Comment: any alternative solution @nwellnhof

Comment: I don't know much about XML schema, but I think it doesn't make sense to have a `xs:simpleType` inside an `xs:attribute` with `use="prohibited"` although it's structurally valid. So simply removing the offending  `xs:simpleType` elements should make no difference. You could also [file an issue in libxml2's bug tracker](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/issues) but this probably won't get addressed unless you provide a patch with a fix yourself.